# Completion handler asynchrony

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with my completion handlers. Here is a function with a completion handler, located in a Utility file:

```
func convertGeopointToCity(geopoint: PFGeoPoint, complete: (city: String, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var city = ""
    let latitude = geopoint.latitude
    let longitude = geopoint.longitude
    let location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in

        if (error == nil) {

            if let p = CLPlacemark?(placemarks![0]) {

                if let city = p.locality {
                    city = " \(city)!"
                    print("Here's the city:\(city)")
                    complete(city: city, error: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

That I call in a ViewController

```
    LocationUtility.instance.convertGeopointToCity(geopoint, complete: { result, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error converting geopoint")
        } else {
            city = result as String
        }
    })
    print("The city: \(city)")
```

The output clearly indicates that the function is not waiting to be completed before running the block:

```
The city: 

Here's the hood Toronto!
```

How do I address this issue?

Comment: works as expected. the completion handler is called as soon as work is done. WHILE that work is done the regular control flow continues - in your case that means that the print statement is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your handler inside of the block:

```
LocationUtility.instance.convertGeopointToCity(geopoint, complete: { result, error in
    if error != nil {
        print("error converting geopoint")
    } else {
        city = result as String
        // do other stuff here, or call a method 
        print("The city: \(city)")
    }
})
```

The `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` is async. The completion block is called as soon as the geocode finished, more likely after your print append.

You should do your operations in another function called by the complete block, or adding some code to the block itself.